# Multiple configuration files for the ProGuard Ant task

Tags: ant, proguard

I am using the ProGuard ant task, and everything is great, except that my ProGuard configuration file is huge.  Also, different tasks use different ProGuard configuration files, and there is a lot of copy-pasting that I would like to refactor into separate .pro files.

```
<taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="C:/Program Files/proguard4.7/lib/proguard.jar"/>
<target name="obfuscated_jar" depends="raw_jar">
    <proguard configuration="core.pro lib1.pro lib2.pro">
        <outjar path="prog_obfuscated.jar"/>
    </proguard>
</target>
```

The above doesn't work, because it treats the multiple .pro files as one big filename.  I'm a known idiot w.r.t. ant, am I missing something obvious?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a single main .pro file that contains `-include` options pointing to your actual .pro files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ProGuard btw, it's great!

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't great, but it works...

```
<taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="C:/Program Files/proguard4.7/lib/proguard.jar"/>
<target name="obfuscated_jar" depends="raw_jar">
    <concat destfile="proguard_temp.pro">
        <filelist dir="." files="core.pro,lib1.pro,lib2.pro"/>
    </concat>
    <proguard configuration="proguard_temp.pro">
        <outjar path="prog_obfuscated.jar"/>
    </proguard>
    <delete file="proguard_temp.pro"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like only one file allowed in `configuration` attribute.
**Edited**
And attributes allowed only on `<proguard>` element. I have another possible solution. Try to concatenate your config-files into one with Ant [concat-task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) and pass this temporary file to `<proguard configuration=""`> attribute.

---

Also, it's possible to modify `ProGuardTask`-class to accept several files as arguments and concatenate them later. And same result could be achieved with Ant `macrodef` .

Comment: Tried it, no luck.  `proguardconfiguration doesn't support the "configuration" attribute`

Comment: Yeah. We thought about same thing. :-)

Comment: Ha!  I guess great minds think alike, and at the same time.  Thanks for the help!  Proguard at the console accepts multiple commands, so I woulda guessed that it would accept multiple in the ant task too, but the concat thing works okay.